# Add a new mesh to an existing mesh with armature

Tags: animation, armature

[image: d]

I select the glasses and then the Armature and ctrl+P and select bones.

But the glasses are not affected by the animation:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: force the glasses vg to be assigned to the bone that leads the head movements. Maybe "spine.006" if you're using metarig.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parenting to the bone, parent to Armature Deform Modifier **With Empty Groups**.

Then switch to edit mode, select all the glasses' mesh with <kbd>A</kbd>, go to Properties Editor > Mesh Data tab > Vertex Groups panel > select the head bone's group (`spine.006` I suppose?) and hit the <kbd>Assign</kbd> button.